# RegEx Splitting to a List<string>

Tags: regex

RegEx is a bit confusing to me and I have been at it for 3.5 hours on one line.

I have a string:

"    Layer 1         Layer 2  Layer    3 Layer 4  "

I would like to split it up into a List and cannot get it to work.
I tried this and it was close but still not what I am looking to do:

```
List<string> lineWords = Regex
    .Matches(line, @"[Layier_]*\s*\s*[1-9]")
    .OfType<Match>().ToArray()
    .Select(match => match.Value)
    .List();
```

Where am I in error?

Thank you.

Comment: What technology (programming language) do you use? Please, put it in the tag.

Comment: Btw a regex to match `Layer x` would be `Layer\s+[1-9]`. No need to use `\s*\s*` (it's equivalent to `\s`). [Layier_]* does not match layer but any word that contains the chars inside `[]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't write it explicitly, but I assume, you are using C#.

Your code requires only minor corrections:

- I changed the regex a little (compare).
- `ToArray()` is not needed.
- Instead of `List()` use `ToList()`.

So the code given below works.

```
List<string> lineWords = Regex.Matches(line, @"[Layier_]+\s*[1-9]")
  .Cast<Match>()
  .Select(match => match.Value)
  .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you.  These RegEx things drive me a bit crazy.  That worked perfect.